# 2-D Array C++ Triangle

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program in c++ that takes in  triangle pattern of numbers into a 2-D array.

Example:

```
    1

   3 4

  5 9 2

 9 4 6 1
```

The top row is one number(integer) and each row of the triangle has one more number than the row above it.

Once the triangle has been entered and/or examined via for loops, the program needs to traverse the triangle from top to bottom and record all possible sums of each path;

The path taken down the triangle must always be adjacent to the number in the row above it.

While traversing down the triangle each "path" should be stored in a new array so the path can be displayed.
After recording the sum for each path down the triangle the program should compare them and display the path with the smallest sum.

With the changes i made so far thanks to @Beta i have this so far:

```
int main()
{   
 int row = 0;
 int col = 0;

 int A[4][4] = {{2},{8,9},{3,4,5},{6,2,9,1}};

for (row = 0; row < 4; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col <= row; col++)
    {
        cout << A[row][col] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

My Output is so far is:

2

8 9

3 4 5

6 2 9 1

Comment: First, your array has 2 rows and 3 columns, but you're accessing from 4 according to your initialization of row. However, the for loop tests for row < 1, which means that since row starts at 4 will not execute that loop. Try from 0 to < 2.

Comment: Ok did that. It executes now. i added more numbers because i need have 4 rows to make this look like a triangle.
Output:

2,3,4

8,9,10

3,4,5

6,2,9

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick you're looking for is this:

```
for (col = 0; col <= row; col ++)
```

I couldn't parse the last part of your question ("After that...").

**EDIT:**

The problem of making the triangle look symmetrical is a problem of printing spaces at the beginning of each line. With the trick above, you should be able to figure than one out.

As for considering all paths and displaying the one with the smallest sum, *what have you tried?* If you are not familiar with Breadth-First Search and Depth-First Search, copying arrays and arrays of pointers, you're probably not ready for this exercise.

Comment: Wow thx it looks somewhat of a triangle now the only weird thing its leaning to left of the screen. Ooo to rephrase that last part what i mean is once the triangle has been entered and/or examined via for loops, the program needs to traverse the triangle from top to bottom and record all possible sums of each path; The path taken down the triangle must always be adjacent to the number in the row above it.

Comment: @Toad: do you have an idea how you want to do that? (There's more than one way.) Are you comfortable with recursion? How about `std::set`?

Comment: Well the other catch to this program that i am doing is that starting from the top of the triangle it will output the smallest path to take going down triangle and it has to be adjacent from the previous row of that number. You was right about the 18 and 8 but when it comes to middle it depends which path is smaller going down

Comment: @Toad: Maybe this is a language barrier, but I don't understand what you wrote. Could you edit your question to show what you want the program to do in your example?

Comment: At this point i am not fully sure on tackling it. I've been at it for a day now. In the question i am force to use a 2-D array :'(